# How do I get values separated by a space and put them in a new list?

Tags: python, list

I want to get the values from a list=[[x,y,a b c],[x,y, d e f],[x,y, g h i]] and put the values from the third element splitted by a space on a new list.

I have tried using 2 for loops to iterate in each list and looking for the 3rd element (the text), split it using a space and storing each word in a new list.

```py
list=[['x','y','a b c'],
['x','y','d e f'],
['x','y','g h i']]

wordsInput=[]
for words in list:
    for palabrasinList in range(len(words)):
        list[words][wordsinList].split(" ")
        individual=list[words][2].split(" ")[wordsinList]
        wordsInput.append(individual)

#Expected result:
    newList=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]
```

I would like the new list to be newList=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i], but somehow the notebook throws me an error. Please help :(.

[EDIT]
This is the error im getting:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-aaefcd3cda7c> in <module>()
      2 for words in list:
      3     for wordsinList in range(len(words)):
----> 4         individual=list[words][2].split(" ")[wordsinList]
      5         wordsInput.append(individual)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Comment: "somehow the notebook throws me an error". OK. What is the exact text of the error are you getting?

Comment: You can't use empty spaces when you're defining a list. You have to separate each element with a comma. ```[x,y,a b c]``` will return an error. The correct way is ```[x,y,a,b,c]```. Also you're referring to variables named x,y,a,b and c. You need to enclose them in quotes to make them strings.

Comment: Just a note on the style of your code. To make it more "pythonic" change your variables to lowercase_underscore, like "words_input". See [Pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions). Also use `enumerate` instead of `range(len())`.

Comment: Also you should not name variables "list" because this is a python keyword, and will make your code confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming those are strings, not variables:

```
list = [['x', 'y', 'a b c'],
        ['x', 'y', 'd e f'],
        ['x', 'y', 'g h i']]
wordsInput=[]
for words in list:
    wordsInput+=words[2].split(" ")
print(wordsInput)
```

OUTPUT

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```